# Can't get Text to update after changing slider

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom embedded View with Text and a Slider that binds to an ObservedObject. I can successfully update the binding with changing the slider but the Text does not update. For some reason, I am really struggling with getting the hang of Property Wrappers and hoping to finally get it to click.

I can easily have the text update when I'm binding the slider value to local state, but no luck with the binding.

```swift
class MyItem:ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case calories
    }

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()
    var id = UUID()
    var calories:Double = 0 { didSet { update() } 

    func update() {
        didChange.send()
    }
}

struct ContentView:View {
    @ObservedObject var item = MyItem()

    var body:some View {
        MySlider(value: $item.calories)
    }
}

struct MySlider:View {
    @Binding var value:Double

    var body:some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value) ")
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...2000, step:5)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I can't get the text in MySlider to update as I mess with the Slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@partha g—I was still getting a message from XCode saying that MyItem didn't conform to Codable. So after some digging, I added a couple inits and encode methods to get everything working the way I was expecting:

```swift
class MyItem: ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {

    [...]

    func encode(to encoder:Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(calories, forKey: .calories)
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        calories = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .calories)
    }
    init() { }
}
```

and voila.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With property wrappers introduced in Swift 5.1, we can user `@Published` to simplify the state propagation.  I refactored yours to user `@Published`. For the scenario mentioned this should work.

```swift
class MyItem: ObservableObject, Codable, Identifiable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case id
      case calories
    }

    var id = UUID()
    @Published var calories: Double = 0
}

struct ContentView:View {
    @ObservedObject var item = MyItem()

    var body:some View {
        MySlider(value: $item.calories)
    }
}

struct MySlider:View {
    @Binding var value:Double

    var body:some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value) ")
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...2000, step:5)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I intended for MyItem to be codable since this would be sent to a service via JSON. Since it needs to be codable, @Published does not conform to Codable.

Comment: I was focusing on slider to figure out why it was not getting updated based on the title.  Updated the code.  Slider is updating the text now.  @manotype.  Let me know that works at your end